# Сравнение чисел с неопределенным количеством показателей степени

Tags: c++, математика

Предположим, есть некое число. Записывается в следующем формате:

```
N B P[1] P[2] .. P[N]
```

где

```
N - количество степеней, 1 <= N <= 10.
B - это основание степени, 1 <= B <= 99.
P[1] .. P[N] - сами степени, 1 <= P[i] <= 99.
```

Таким образом число, представленное как

```
4 2 3 4 5 6
```

Это 2^(3^(4^(5^6))), то есть вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращу внимание, что ***степени считаются справа налево***, то есть сначала 5 возводим в степень 6, только потом 4 в степень того, что получилось и т. д.

### **Необходимо определить, какое из двух заданных в таком формате чисел наибольшее.**

---

Основная проблема этой задачи в том, что если взять, например, число 2^(2^(2^(2^2))), то это получится 2^65536, что не поместится ни в один целочисленный тип данных (особенно если учесть, что основание и все последующие степени могут быть равны 99, в таком случае число получится огромным).

Пробовал логарифмировать с обеих сторон, тогда на 3м этапе заходим в тупик, т.е.:

```
Числа: 2^(3^(4^(5^6))) и 4^(9^(5^2))

log(2^(3^(4^(5^6))))  ??  log(4^(9^(5^2)))
Выносим показатели степени за знак логарифма:
(3^(4^(5^6))) * log(2)  ??  (9^(5^2)) * log(4)
Снова логарифмируем:
log(3^(4^(5^6))) * log(2))  ??  log(9^(5^2)) * log(4))
log(3^(4^(5^6))) + log(log(2))  ?? log(9^(5^2)) + log(log(4))
4^(5^6) * log(3) + log(log(2))  ?? 5^2 * log(9) + log(log(4))
```

При дальнейшем логарифмировании необходимо брать логарифм суммы, который уже не особо-то и раскрывается и  в итоге ничего из этого не выходит.
Как быть?

Comment: Это итерируемая система счисления. В вашем случае башенная. Шаг веса логарифмический. Соответственно число представляется в виде f(f(...f(x))). Для начала стоит взять меньшие ограничения и покрутить. Где-то у меня был алгоритм сравнения, поищу.

Comment: @becouse с нетерпением жду

Comment: Ваша задача обсуждается в этом форуме https://www.sql.ru/forum/1198598-4/algoritmy

также вам может помочь Суперлогарифм https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Answer (score 3):

```
2^(3^(4^(5^6))) и 4^(9^(5^2))
```

Логарифмируем

```
log 2 * 3^(4^(5^6))                       log 4 * 9^(5^2)
```

Логарифмируем

```
log log 2 + log 3 * 4^(5^6)               log log 4 + log 9 * (5^2)
```

Пренебрегаем мелкими двойными логарифмами!

```
log 3 * 4^(5^6)                           log 9 * (5^2)
```

Логарифмируем

```
log log 3 + log 4 * 5^6                   log log 9 + log 5 * 2
```

Пренебрегаем мелкими двойными логарифмами! Логарифмируем

```
log log 4 + 6 * log5                      log log 5 + log 2
```

Далее очевидно, что больше? :)

Это тот случай, когда если даже число записать в виде 10^N, то N будет с большой погрешностью...

Такие вопросы [уже задавались](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707292/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB/707296#707296), кстати.

Comment: Если пренебречь мелкими двойными логарифмами, то точность упадет процентов на 30, т. к., например, log(log(99)) = 1.5 примерно, что может сыграть критическую роль в сравнении чисел с примерно одинаковыми степенями (предположим, отличается только одна степень на 1).

Comment: Когда речь идет о числах такого порядка - говорить о 30% не приходится. Дай вам Бог поймать с точностью 30% N в записи 10^10^N... Как говорится - не хотите - не верьте, но дело обстоит именно так.

Comment: Например, 4^5^6 - это уже порядок 10^9407. После того, как вы возведете 3 в эту степень - это будет 10 в степени N, где N - число с 9406 нулями. Прикидываете? Вопрос уже не стоит о том, с какой цифры это число начинается :) При нем log 2 - это не то что пренебрежимо мало, это просто ничто...

Comment: @Harry а код есть? Просто мне лично кажется, что пренебрегать нельзя. Иначе можно получить близкие степени вида 10^3 и 2 ^ 10 наприер. или подобное. Проверить интересно)

Comment: @Harry log2 пренебрежимо мало, если сравнивать с возведенным в степень числом, но если сравнивать с произведением логарифмов от показателей степеней (тут же мы ничего не возводим), то тут уже log2 может, опять же, сыграть решающую роль.

Comment: @pavel Да какой код это в состоянии потянуть? Ручка, бумажка. Тут даже Wolfram ласты клеит на 4 возведении в степень. Я бы дал ссылку на книжку, но уже не помню, у кого про это читал... У Литтлвуда, что ли. Нет, не помню. Вобщем, тут реально первые степени не играют никакой роли - это надо настолько подобрать что-то настолько точно , что я просто и представить не могу :) Разве что большие показатели будут одинаковы - но тогда вы увидите разницу гораздо раньше.

Comment: @Harry да на бумажке лень) думал есть код который это делает чтобы подобрать неправильный ответ.

Comment: Ну, переубедить я не могу. Возьмите ручку, бумажку, калькулятор. Прикиньте погрешности. Я тоже в свое время не хотел верить - мозг отказывался :) Но потом убедился.

Comment: @Harry 87^2^10 и 97^10^3 отличаются всего в 5 раз. и это я ещё не искал)

Comment: Еще наблюдение: самая последняя степень (т. е. та, которую, по сути, мы должны вычислять первой), сильнее всего влияет на итоговое число. При изменении более "приземленных" степеней число меняется намного меньше, чем при изменении "верхушек".

Comment: @VitalySusanin на этом и основан метод по сути. но не всё так просто)

Comment: @pavel Да, но здесь пренебрегать рано :) log log 87+10 log 2 - тут я не предлагал пренебрегать. А вот допишите еще штук 5 степеней и посмотрите, что будет глубоко все равно - 87 внизу или 97... Посмотрите - в последней строке ответа я не писал "пренебрегаем двойными логарифмами" :) Кстати, можно и на предпоследней посчитать - там тоже можно не пренебрегать...

Comment: @Harry ну вообще нет) примем как допущение, что  87^2^10 = a и  97^10^3 = 5*a. (там чуть больше но это мелочи). Запишем 2^5a и 32^a. точность нужно по прежнему даже при двойном логарифмировании. Калькулятор уже не вывозит) или нет. сейчас пересчитаю.

Comment: @Harry  `log(34)*87^2^10 / (log(2)*97^10^3)
 ~1.00573060316586875494` ну как бы... Используя 6 нижних степеней я могу ещё больше приблизить.

Comment: @pavel Вы придумываете искусственные примеры. Да, если подбирать какие-то дробные числа с многими тысячами знаков - можно добиться совпадений. Но ни одна машина их реально не потянет. Вобщем, я свое сказал, если кто хочет - пусть напишет решение лучше. Будет интересно посмотреть :)

Comment: это не дробные числа) числа целые все. поэтому и хотел решение в коде, чтобы проверить идею. Я попробую с другой стороны подойти.

Comment: `log log 2 + log 3 * 4^(5^6)` Имеем: -0.52139 и рядом 7.345x10^9406. Вы всерьез считаете, что этим 0.5 нельзя пренебречь? Вы всерьез собираетесь вычислить log3 с точностью 9407 знаков? :)

Comment: @Harry ну смотрите. `34^87^2^10` и  `2^97^10^3` после логарифмов получилось `log log 87 + 10 * log (2)` ~ 3.297994 и `log log 97 + 3 * log (10)` ~3.2981 вроде как второе больше. Но если логарифмировать один раз, то получим наоборот. Потому что мы теряем инфу о 34 и 2 к последнему шагу. А это важно тут.

Comment: @pavel Вы мне поясните, что вы хотите доказать? Неуниверсальность метода? Так я вроде нигде и не утверждал, что он абсолютно универсален :)

Comment: @Harry извиняюсь. я думал вы говорили что метод рабочий для любых таких вещей. Видимо не так понял вашу фразу.